# How can I configure Gnome Shell Notification settings?

Tags: 11.10, configuration, gnome, notification, settings

I couldn't find where I can change Gnome Shell notification settings. I clicked the button that appears with "Don't Show Again" (or something like that) label on a notification, and now when that notification appears, it never disappears until I click on that.

Where is the configuration window of Gnome Shell notifications?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to easily configure gnome-shell notifications as of yet. You can disable them or configure them to time out.

dconf-editor allows you to configure some settings

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
dconf-editor
```

You can also modify `notify-send` so the messages are transient.

```
# Move the current script to a backup location
sudo mv /usr/bin/notify-send /usr/bin/notify-send.bak
```

Now, use gedit for a new wrapper script

```
gksu gedit /usr/bin/notify-send
```

copy-paste this into that file

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/notify-send --hint int:transient:1 "$@"
```

Save the script , exit gedit, and make it executable

```
sudo chmod a+x /usr/bin/notify-send
```

See also [this forums post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11453194) for addition suggestions.

Comment: Are you sure your answer will work as intended? `/usr/bin/notify-send --hint int:transient:1 "$@"` will call `/usr/bin/notify-send` which contains `/usr/bin/notify-send --hint int:transient:1 "$@"`, you will fall into a recursive script with no end. **usr/bin/notify-send** should contain `/usr/bin/notify-send.bak --hint int:transient:1 "$@"`, no?