# How can I disable all GNOME Shell notifications?

Tags: gnome, notification

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I configure Gnome Shell Notification settings?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/76446/how-can-i-configure-gnome-shell-notification-settings)

I recently switched to GNOME Shell. Everything works great expect that I keep getting notifications of wired disconnects and one about mail. Is there anyway to disable all notifications in GNOME Shell?